# Python - Compare items in list of tuples

Tags: python

I have two lists of tuples (item name, version) - one containing all current items, the other containing items to import. If there is a name clash between imported and current items I want to return the newer version. My solution is:

```
currentItemVersion = [("ItemA", "001"), ("ItemB", "002"), ("Camera", ""), ("SHD_metal", "001"), ("SHD_wood", "002")]
importItemVersion = [("ItemB", "001"), ("Camera", "001"), ("SHD_metal", "002"), ("SHD_wood", "004")]

def updateItems(currentItems, importItems):
    updatedItems = []
    for i, v in currentItemVersion:
        if i in [n[0] for n in importItemVersion]:
            ni, nv = importItemVersion[[n[0] for n in importItemVersion].index(i)]
            nvInt = int(nv) if nv else -1
            vInt = int(v) if v else -1
            if nvInt > vInt:
                updatedItems.append((ni, nv))
            elif nvInt == vInt:
                updatedItems.append((ni, nv))
            else:
                updatedItems.append((i, v))
        else:
            print('item {0} was not imported'.format(i))
            updatedItems.append((i, v))
    return updatedItems

print(updateItems(currentItemVersion, importItemVersion))
```

I am wondering if there is a nicer solution for this, especially in lines 7 & 8. Can I somehow check

```
if i in [n[0] for n in list]
```

and return n[1] in a single operation?

Comment: If this works and you want to get feedback on the code and implementation, you should take it to Code Review

Comment: I was not aware of this option, thank you for forwarding me there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dict and update the items one by one, while checking version by the one that is already in the dict if available, for example:

```
currentItemVersion = [("ItemA", "001"), ("ItemB", "002"), ("Camera", ""), ("SHD_metal", "001"), ("SHD_wood", "002")]
importItemVersion = [("ItemB", "001"), ("Camera", "001"), ("SHD_metal", "002"), ("SHD_wood", "004")]

def updateItems(currentItems, importItems):
    updated = {}
    for item, ver in currentItems + importItems:
        try:
            if int(ver) > int(updated.get(item, 0)):
                updated[item] = ver

        except ValueError:
            updated[item] = ver

    return updated

print updateItems(currentItemVersion, importItemVersion)
```

Output:

```
{'ItemB': '002', 'ItemA': '001', 'Camera': '001', 'SHD_wood': '004', 'SHD_metal': '002'}
```

`dict.get(item, 0)` returns version if item is a valid key, and `0` if not.
You might want to type cast versions to `int()` before comparing.

Edit:

Added `int()` type cast + `try/except` to catch exception when trying to type cast `""` to `int()`

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: Actually if you wanted to avoid the typecast you could just leave them as strings

Comment: @maxymoo but then if a version doesn't have leading zeroes things will get mixed up, since `'4' > '11'` is `True`

Answer (score 2):

Use dict instead, that way you don't need to find the key clash with a inner loop, and reduce the complexity from O(m*n) to O(m).